# Real time audio between android devices

Tags: android

I am trying to build an Android application where I can transmit real time audio between two android devices, most likely the easiest way of doing this is going to be with a sever in the middle. Any help/direction/guidance is very much appreciated.

Been searching for a library to aid the process and haven't found a helpful one.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look on multithreaded server and client socket programming [click here](http://www.ase.md/~aursu/ClientServerThreads.html)

here in chat application client sends string to the server similarly in your case. client wil read the whole data send the data in byte[] format to the server. here server sends the response to the sae client using socket of the client but in your case the server will send the same data to the recipient client using socket of that client.

Alsio you can have a look [here also](http://freecode-freecode.blogspot.com/2008/06/multi-threaded-programming.html)

Donot forget to vote if my answer is helpful for you.

Thanks
Deepak.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly send a file from one device to another device using blue tooth. There is no need of server in between them. the other way is to use server and client communication.  There is one server and multiple clients. when your client starts application it will create socket connection with server. when it want to send to the recepient device the client have to send the information of recipient device to the server and the audio file also. then server will check for the the device whether it is connected with the server. If connected then server will send the file to the recipient.

Do not forget to vote if the response is helpful for you.

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: Hi Deepak, thanks for the information, do you possibly have some sample code to get me started?